# Spell email address for forums

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

How can I make the code of the mail to spell it  and undetectable for forum when I try to put it in html

Thank's anticipated

Like this ! but more sophisticated

```
<h>mariaburkke76</h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h>@<h><h><h><h><h>g<h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h>m<h><h><h>a<h><h>i<h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h>l<h><h><h><h>.<h>com<h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h><h>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Your question is confusing to me.

Comment: That protection is .... https://3v4l.org/GNNvq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) (w/ random key) and base64/atob.

**Though it wont stop a bot which is specifically designed to scrape your forum, see below.**

```
<?php
$email = '<a href="mailto:mariaburkke76@gmail.com">mariaburkke76@gmail.com</a>';

function xor_email($str) {
    $key = mt_rand(1, 192);
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $str[$i] = chr(ord($str[$i]) ^ $key);
    }
    return $key.'.'.base64_encode($str);
}
$enc = xor_email($email);
?>

<e data-enc='<?= $enc ?>'/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script>
var decode = function(key, hash) {
    var salt = parseInt(key);
    var result = '';
    for (var i=0; i<hash.length; i++) {
        result += String.fromCharCode(salt ^ hash.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return result;
}
$(document).find('e').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('enc').split(".");
    $(this).replaceWith(decode(data[0], atob(data[1])));
});
</script>
```

Would generate the following.

```html
<e data-enc='102.WgdGDhQDAFtECwcPChIJXAsHFA8HBBMUDQ0DUVAmAQsHDwpIBQkLRFgLBxQPBwQTFA0NA1FQJgELBw8KSAUJC1pJB1g='/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script>
var decode = function(key, hash) {
    var salt = parseInt(key);
    var result = '';
    for (var i=0; i<hash.length; i++) {
        result += String.fromCharCode(salt ^ hash.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return result;
}
$(document).find('e').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data('enc').split(".");
    $(this).replaceWith(decode(data[0], atob(data[1])));
});
</script>
```

---

From a harvesters point of view, once determined the method of protection one could easily scrape out the email as followed. Just so you're under no illusions that security through obscurity will not protect you from a custom-made email bot/scraper/harvester.

```
<?php
$html = '<e data-enc=\'102.WgdGDhQDAFtECwcPChIJXAsHFA8HBBMUDQ0DUVAmAQsHDwpIBQkLRFgLBxQPBwQTFA0NA1FQJgELBw8KSAUJC1pJB1g=\'/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<script>
var decode = function(key, hash) {
    var salt = parseInt(key);
    var result = \'\';
    for (var i=0; i<hash.length; i++) {
        result += String.fromCharCode(salt ^ hash.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return result;
}
$(document).find(\'e\').each(function(){
    var data = $(this).data(\'enc\').split("-");
    $(this).replaceWith(decode(data[0], atob(data[1])));
});
</script>';

function xor_email($str, $key) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $str[$i] = chr(ord($str[$i]) ^ $key);
    }
    return $str;
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);

//
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('e') as $e) {
    // parse out XORed string
    $enc = $e->getAttribute('data-enc');
    $enc = explode('.', $enc);
    $decoded = xor_email(base64_decode($enc[1]), $enc[0]);

    // parse out email
    $sub_doc = new DOMDocument();
    $sub_doc->loadHTML($decoded);
    foreach ($sub_doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
        echo $a->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/T0mlp

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ROT13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) simple cipher. It is used to screen out spam bots.