# Get and modify all mail addresses from a string

Tags: php

I am trying to encode (replace each letter with the character's ASCII value, to prevent spam) all mail adresses from a string. My idea so far was to replace the mails with a pattern but I haven't managed to then encode the mail address.

```
function replace_mail($string) {
    $pattern = "<[\w.]+@[\w.]+>";
    $replacement = encode_email(MAILADDRESS);
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
```

For example:

```
replace_mail('This is a string with a mail@gmail.com to contact us.');
// Output should be: This is a string with a &#109;&#097;&#105;&#108;&#064;&#103;&#109;&#097;&#105;&#108;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109; to contact us.
```

The encode function for reference:

```
function encode_email($e) {
    $output = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($e); $i++) { $output .= '&#'.ord($e[$i]).';'; }
    return $output;
}
```

I've been looking for a solution for quite a long time now - without success. So now I hope to find one here.

Comment: What? what do you mean by _encode all mail adresses from a string_?

Comment: +Mehdi Bounya To get the emails and replacing each letter with the character's ASCII value, to provide spam.

Comment: Can you give a data sample and the expected result?

Comment: +Lawrence Cherone Sorry, to prevent spam of course.

Comment: By the way, use @ to mention people not +

Comment: @mmibm its a little confusing as to what you want, what about doing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725062/spell-email-address-for-forums/47725462#47725462

Comment: "<[\w.]+@[\w.]+>" will fail to match a lot of valid ADDR_SPECs (I don't think you really mean email addresses in the formal sense as defined in RFC 5322)

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. May be this helps. Do let me know..`

```
<?php
function replace_mail($string) {
    $pattern = "<[\w.]+@[\w.]+>";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $match);
    $replacement = encode_email($match[0][0]);
    return  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}
function encode_email($e) {
    $output = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($e); $i++)
    {
      $ascii=ord($e[$i]);
      $output[$i]= $ascii;
    }
    $output="&amp;#".implode(";&amp;#",$output);
    return $output;
}
echo replace_mail('This is a string with a mail@gmail.com to contact us.');

?>
```